# How to turn off touchbar only when second monitor is connected?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, mojave

Is it possible to automatically disable/turn off the touch-bar on macOS Mojave when I connect to a second monitor?

I find it annoying to see the touch-bar light up every time I type or mouse click from the corner of my eye. Since I have a second, main monitor the touch-bar is useless to me when I have the second monitor plugged in.

So: Is it possible to automatically turn off the touch-bar only when I have my second monitor plugged in?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Regarding your question, there's no *automatic* way I'm aware of. However, you could set up a service and/or keyboard shortcut that changes the Touch Bar from it's default appearance to either the Control Strip or Function Keys as required. And of course, back again to its default when not required. There are also 3rd party utilities that effectively do the same thing. Would this suffice?

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome. Yes, what you mention would suffice and would accept an answer based on what you suggest above. :)

Comment: I think it could be done... I'm thinking I would personally need [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) and [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/)... and it would be incredibly convoluted considering how simple the concept is... but I would use KBM to automatically detect that there's 2 monitors connected and then feed this info to BTT via applescript and have it change the touchbar. Not sure if BTT can turn it fully off though. I tried to find a way to turn off the touchbar using aplescript, but I didn't find anything...

Comment: @Joonas, thanks for your comment. Yes, indeed the idea is rather simple and can't understand how this was not thought of or asked before. Especially in low light conditions, the touch bar being constantly turned on and off from the corner of my eye is pretty annoying. I will look into the suggestions